# 40+ clients on home router + repeater, but the communication fails after a few hours

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I have around 43 Embedded devices(2.4GHz band) connected to home router(Netgear N300). What I have found is that my Netgear router does not allow more than 32 DHCP clients to connect. Hence I put a repeater(Dlink DIR 816, dual antenna, DHCP server disabled) just to extend the router client table capacity. This was successfully accomplished as all my 43 embedded devices and 3 computers remain connected to the main router. The devices connect to a TCP server hosted on a computer which is assigned a static IP in router table. I avoid half broken pipe in TCP by sending "ALIVE" packets from server to my devices every 1 second. If the device fails to receive this packet in a 5 second window, it breaks the connection and reconnects. This setup has worked for a few months, but now I have encountered a weird problem. After a few hours of operation, my devices stop receiving these "ALIVE" packets and continuously make and break connections. Once I restart my computer everything becomes normal for next few hours. I am unable to identify what the issue might be.
Following points I have deduced:
1. It is not computer problem as I have changed the computer hosting TCP server but the issue remains
2. It is not router problem as even when I restart the router the issue does not go away
3. It is not TCP server problem as even if I restart my TCP server the connect-disconnect cycle continues

Can anybody help me about what might be causing this problem?
(All the communications with my device are limited to a few bytes)

Answer (score 0):

So you're sending 43 `alive` packets over TCP via Wi-Fi *per second* using a $40 router. TCP transmission implies unicast delivery with acknowledgements - over wifi, 43 times per second. It makes me think the Wi-Fi access point hardware is the weakest point here (let alone that 43 devices is just too much for a home grade router).

To check the connection over Wi-Fi, make your embedded devices ping your server over ICMP. The devices may not have `ping` application available, but it's pretty straingforwand to implement by yourself.

If the AP is broken, you'll probably see a wide range of response times: from 100 ms to 3 seconds.

If this theory proves true, you may also want to revise your system's architecture. TCP is a heavy thing. It doesn't support multicast whereas UDP, IP and WiFi do (though I'm not sure about the last). Single multicasted `alive` message to all clients instead of 43 TCP transmissions should greatly reduce the load on your network.

Comment: Thanks for your time and advice. I have multiple such setups at different locations. The same router-repeater configuration has been handling 55+ devices without causing a problem. It is only in one place where I am facing this weird issue. So I think the router should not be an issue either. Also the same thing was working even in this location for past 4 months, it is only a few days back that this problem has surfaced. Also as the devices are in remote location I cannot reprogram them either. Can I use wireshark to diagnose further?

Comment: @TariqMerchant if you don't have issues with other instances of the system it doesn't mean one of your routers can't fail after 4 months of operation. Machines break. If you can't reprogram devices, just wait when the system starts to fail and try to ping computer-computer connections (I'm assuming they're wirelessly connected as well). You can use wireshark for this as well. A good place to start: look for ICMP messages about transmission failures.

Comment: The reason I dont feel that router is the troublemaker is because internet works fine over it. I can easily access the router page, look at attached devices, browse internet etc. Also restarting the router makes no change, but restarting the computer rectifies the problem. I assume replacing the router would be the last resort.

Comment: @TariqMerchant yeah I've got your point. I'd start with the router and network diagnostics because they're the simplest things to check. Looking at wireshark logs at the server may give you insight: severe connectivity issues? devices and the server converge to an unlucky state? ICMP messages flood the network? etc. With this amount of devices and software there's great amount of possible failure points.